# Facebook scraping is wrong

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook's scraper is not working. I have updated and deployed my website. I verified the changes by Viewing Page Source. But according to [the debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), Facebook still scrapes what the page used to be. I waited overnight and tried it again, but it still says it is scraping what the page used to be. I used a VPN to visit the site from various places but same thing. This is the first website I have tried to get this working with. I tried adding a hash to the url in the debug tool. It then said "This URL hasn't been shared on Facebook before". I clicked "Fetch new information" and it scraped the old information again. I tried entering the url into the batch invalidator. I clicked debug and got "Some of the input URLs were ignored because they are Facebook URLs or exceeded the maximum input." The url is only 19 characters long.

EDIT: I think this has something to do with the fact that I edited Netlify's url for the site. At first it was some random combination of characters. Then I discovered that I can replace that with something meaningful. So I did that.

After hitting this problem, I changed the name back to its original name. I checked the Facebook og info and it was for the old version. Then I re-scraped and this time it got the new version. Then I switched the Netlify site name again back to my preferred one. I checked the og info. It was for the old version. I re-scraped. It was still for the old version.

EDIT: I don't think this is due to my changing the Netlify site name. With the name what it originally was, I pushed another update with different og information. I verified the new information by using a VPN to visit the site from different places. I then had Facebook re-scrape the page, but it still had the old information. This is a problem with the Facebook scraper.

EDIT: I updated og:image and pushed the change, then re-scraped. It still shows the old value of og:image on the Facebook scrape debugger in the list of scraped values, but when I test it by pasting the site into a Facebook message it displays the new og:image along with the old og:title.

I don't understand. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the netlify pre-rendering checkbox set. Pre-rendering serves cached index.html files to crawlers and updates them every 24-48 hours.